# Visualize App Insights Data Stored in SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, powerbi, telemetry

I have an asp.net application which uses App Insights SDK to get the telemetry data. I can see the data in the Azure portal. All is good.

Now, I [export that data](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/app-insights-export-telemetry/) to a SQL database. It gets exported in JSON format continuously.

After many days, I need to show that telemetry in visualization form to my team. Can it be done in any way using already existing tools?

I don't want to do a lot of data munging again and hope Microsoft has something.

Please let me know if it can be done using PowerBI or in some other way.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some historical information can be shown in Power BI using the content pack. See https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-content-pack-application-insights/. You don't need any export for that.

Other than that, data in sql server can be visualized using many tools. If you store your data as json in sql server you could use Power BI since it can handle json very well. Otherwise you might be better of parsing the json before inserting it to the db and insert it in specialized tables and columns. Then you can use Power Bi or Reporting Services (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx) or whatever tool you like best.

If you have access to sql server 2016: that version has some support for json as well. So you can query json in columns easier.